# How can I rotate my custom AlertDialog permanently?

Tags: android, rotation, android-alertdialog

I have a custom dialog. I use the following code to create it in "onCreateDialog" method:

```
Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this,
            android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen));

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View productsView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.dialog_photo_gallery,
            null);
    builder.setView(productsView);
    galProducts = (Gallery) productsView.findViewById(R.id.galProducts);
    ...
```

I have used the [link](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg48333.html) for creating a custom LinearLayout that supports rotation.

I want to use my custom LinearLayout class and set my resource layout to it? I do not want to declare my controls dynamically in the source code. I want to do something like this:

```
RotateLinearLayout myLayout= new RotateLinearLayout(this);
myLayout.setResourceView(R.layout.dialog_photo_gallery);
```

How can I do that?

How can I use AlertDialog.Builder and my RotateLinearLayout Simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap up your controls described in R.layout.dialog_photo_gallery to your RotateLinearLayout

something like that:

```
<com.xxx.RotateLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <Gallery android:id="@+id/galProducts
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</com.xxx.RotateLinearLayout>
```

And then:

```
public class MyDialog extends AlertDialog {
    public MyDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_photo_gallery, null);
        setView(view);
        galProducts = (Gallery) view.findViewById(R.id.galProducts);       
    }
}
```